Lecturers in my department presenting on a similar topic to me
Last year I presented my PHD topic at a conference and some lecturers from my university attended. This year I am presenting at the same conference. I can see the lecturers are again  also attending and are giving a presentation on a similar topic to me. Is this bad form? Should they have been in touch with me to say they are now working on a similar topic? Should I contact them or my supervisor about this?

You should always be able to talk to your supervisor about things you're uncertain about; it need not be an Official Contact, you're just asking them about what you're experiencing and seeking advice. It's okay if they respond "don't worry about this".

It may strongly depend on how similar the topic actually is, which we can't know reading this.

The presentation has a similar title to my thesis title. It is not exactly the same so I don’t think it’s plagiarism I just wonder if people who work in the same department to me should inform me or be open that they are working on a similar topic to me.

Not necessarily. Even if you invented the whole subject from scratch (which I doubt), once you put it in the public domain, it becomes a free game for everyone except for the usual obligation to give the formal credit where it is due. It is, of course, polite and often quite beneficial to share and discuss the results with other people interested in the subject, especially the colleagues, but it is neither required, nor enforced through any "ethical standards".

Do I need to worry that I haven’t published my research yet. It will be finished next year, so what if they try to publish something first?

This notion that one "owns" a certain topical niche in their research group or institution always feels like a bad practice to me. You have presumably not asked anybody except your advisor for approval before selecting what you are interested in studying. Why can't other people do the same?

Think in a positive way, no competition but collaboration. Talk to your supervisor to see whether your team can work with them to do more on the topic.
Your work has been published and presented, so it's your work. Anyone in the world can work on a similar topic and explore further based on your work. The purpose to present your work at a conference is to introduce your work to the others and get their attention. They work on it, which means your work is important and meaningful.
If they don't want collaboration, then you need to work harder and quicker. Get your new achievement published before they do.
My first-year PhD topic was presented by someone next-door. I was very angry, but claim down and move forward. There are millions of interesting topics and I am confident that I can do much better than them. So now, I am an active academic in top university.
